# Adding text before displaying the list of tables

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I am retrieving a list of tables from the database and I want to do some HTML formatting before and after the table list. And also want to report this display to word format.
Can it be done??

my query is

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLES
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND TABLE_NAME <> 'dtProperties'
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

and I want to do some formatting when the value populates in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

What formating do you need? Ex.

```
select '<table>' union all
SELECT '<tr><td>'+TABLE_NAME+'</td></tr>' AS TABLES
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND TABLE_NAME <> 'dtProperties'
union all
select '</table>'
```